# Can a RDBMS have its datadir on another machine

Tags: mysql, rdbms, datadirectory

I am playing with mysql and the command `select @@datadir;` has got me thinking.For someone like me without the means to have a dedicated server i am relegated to cheap vps's which are no good since once my disk space quota is consumed,there is no adjusting my quota upwards.

Since a new connection would be a new thread,i imagine it would be convinient to have some form of network multithreading with my datadir sitting at dropbox or google.is there a database system which allow one access a datadir across a network?.

Comment: Performance would most likely be abysmal. But unless the dbms specifically checks for such a thing, as long as the remote dir is properly mounted, the fact that it's on an entirely different server is going to be transparent to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL database requires a directory path.

You could fool it to use NFS. However, be warned that "standard" linux NFS is not a very good solution: it introduces locks which may lead to lockdown of database (experienced).

Otherwise some storage devices provide with their own NFS clients.

Or you could use SAN/NAS/Whatever. I would further suggest that what you may be looking for is a separate storage device, not a separate "machine".

Comment: My answer applies to MySQL only, as the question is tagged with "MySQL". It may not apply to any other RDBMS